# SOLVED - Magento Layout File Doesn't Work

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout, blocks, extensions

I have created a module and when I put its block in magento catalog.xml it shows up. But when I place the code in my module's productcomments.xml layout file, it doesn't show anything.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cpstest_ProductComments>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Cpstest_ProductComments>
    </modules>
    <frontend>     
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productcomments>
                    <file>productcomments.xml</file>
                </productcomments>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <productcomments>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Cpstest_ProductComments</module>
                    <frontName>productcomments</frontName>
                </args>
            </productcomments>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
         <productcomments_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Cpstest_ProductComments</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                   <class>Cpstest_ProductComments_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!---->
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_setup>
            <productcomments_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_write>
            <productcomments_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </productcomments_read>
        </resources> 
        <helpers>
            <productcomments>
                <class>Cpstest_ProductComments_Helper</class>                                                             
            </productcomments>
        </helpers>
    </global>  
</config>
```

This is productcomments.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">    
                 <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.comments" as="additional" template="productcomments/productcomments.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product Comments</value></action>
                </block>                
            </reference>
       </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

And the working code in catalog.xml is:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">        
     <reference name="content">
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
     <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.comments" as="additional" template="productcomments/productcomments.phtml">
     <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product Comments</value>     </action>
 </block>
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your **productcomments.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">    
             <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.comments" as="comments" template="productcomments/productcomments.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value">
                    <value>Product Comments</value>
                </action>
            </block>                
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Guys thanks so much for your help. Looks like I was missing the <layout>.. Wow I spend 2 days for this.. Really really appreciate the help from both of you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
   <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
```

I doubt above syntax will not work, And also you miss start `layout`

try below code , and your `productcomments.xml` would be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">    
             <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.comments" as="additional" template="productcomments/productcomments.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product Comments</value></action>
            </block>                
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `config.xml` try adding a `module` tag to the layout update.

Here's how I have it in mind:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <productcomments module="Cpstest_ProductComments">
            <file>productcomments.xml</file>
        </productcomments>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried, but that didn't work.